# program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault, ./sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a simple hypergeometric test in c.
This code works for small numbers but fails for large numbers.

for example: hyperG  35 50 90 3400  -- works

but hyperG  ./hyperG  307107    486302    9073845   12147105  --fails

using an online debugger I get:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__ieee754_log_avx (x=2898563) at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c:76
76      ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c: No such file or directory.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

code follows:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <math.h>
  /*
   * program: hyperG
   * purpose: Calculate a probability based on a hypergeometric distribution
   * input  : k, n, M, N
   * output : Return a probability
   * 
   */
  // Variables
  double k = 0.0;
  double n = 0.0;
  double M = 0.0;
  double N = 0.0;

  double logchoos( double n, double k);
  double logfact( double n);

//Probability of at least k out of n tries of having something
//that occurs M of of N times
double hypergeometric( double k, double n, double M, double N)
{
    double p = 0.0;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = k; i <= n; i++){
        p += exp(logchoos((N-M),(n-i)) + logchoos(M,i) - logchoos(N,n));
    }

    return p;
}

// compute log "n choose k" or n = n!/(n-k)!k!
double logchoos( double n, double k) 
{
    double result = logfact(n) - logfact(n-k) - logfact(k);

    return result;
}

// Calculate the log factorial 
double logfact( double n )
{
    double fac;

    if( n < 1)
        return 0.0;
    else
       fac =  log(n) + logfact(n-1);

    return(fac);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Get command line arguments
    k = atof(argv[1]);
    n = atof(argv[2]);
    M = atof(argv[3]);
    N = atof(argv[4]);

    double prob = hypergeometric(k,n,M,N);

    printf("%e\n",prob);

    return 0;
}
```

My MakeFile:

```
Makefile 
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -lm
FILES = hyperG.c

build:  $(FILES) 
    $(CC) $(FILES) -o hyperG $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) 
clean:
    rm -f hyperG
```

Comment: I looks like it cannot find your math shared library `libm`.

Comment: As its working for smaller values but fails for larger values, its probably running out of stack in recursive logfact function

Comment: How do I get the compiler to find the library?  The lib is located: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a

Comment: ldconfig -p | grep libm  shows   libm.so.6 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /lib32/libm.so.6
 libm.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its working for smaller values but fails for larger values, its probably running out of stack, if you change recursion to while loop, it does not segfaults for 307107 486302 9073845 12147105 as input, although it takes lot of time to complete execution

```
double logfact( double n )
{
    double fac = 0;
    while(n > 1)
    {
        fac += log(n);
        n = n-1;
    }

    return(fac);
}
```